# CoreData ascending:YES, show latest from the bottom

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have list of messages in my Core Data store(100 messages).

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:20];
```

It shows only first 20 messages in the order I need. 
What I need to do is: Show last 20 messages, sorted by date of creation, but they should appeared form the bottom of the TableView.

```
Storage: 
1 : Test 1
2 : Test 2
3 : Test 3

It shows now as : 
1 : Test 1
2 : Test 2

**Supposed to show in table View:**

3 : Test 3
2 : Test 2
1 : Test 1
```

**fetchedResultsController:**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Messages" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:20];

    NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(owner = %@) and (stream == %@) and (topic == %@)", ownerGuid,openStream,currentTopic];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:NULL];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: you have `(owner = %@)` when you should have `(owner == %@)`

Comment: One is the assignment operator, the other is the equality operator.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is change the sortDescriptor to use `ascending:NO` so that it will get the last 20 messages.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created" ascending:NO];
```

Now, you've got the right messages, they're just backwards in your array. You can easily reverse an array using the following code.

```
NSArray *messages = [[[fetchedMessages] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

**EDIT:**

Since you using a `NSFetchedResultsController` this solution would require a lot of additional code to work.

The easiest solution I can think of would be implement a custom method for getting your objects out of a fetched results controller.

```
- (id)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger sectionCount = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
    NSInteger newRowIndex = sectionCount - indexPath.row - 1;
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:indexPath.section];

    return [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];
}
```

Then just replace

```
[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

with

```
[self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Can you show me an example. How I could return that in fetchedResultsController ? I attached your code.

Comment: I can't user an array. Because I call that: [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]

Answer (score 0):

@Clever answer is working for me. I called only `NSIndexPath` (return newIndexPath). I did not override method of the `objectAtIndexPath`. I was replaced below method.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)objectNewIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSInteger sectionCount = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
NSInteger newRowIndex = sectionCount - indexPath.row - 1;
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:indexPath.section];

return newIndexPath;
}
```

Then just replace

```
[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self objectNewIndexPath:indexPath];
```